# Get string from Server.UrlEncode as uppercase

Tags: c#, encoding, urlencode

I want its output as uppercase. This is what I get on `Server.UrlEncode("http://")`:

```
http%3a%2f%2f
```

but I need:

```
http%3A%2F%2F
```

Is there built-in solution in C#?

---

The url encoded shall serve as signature base string (input to signature algorithm) to create digest (hash). 
The hash will then be verified by other system (java,php,etc), so they need to recreate the hash by signature reconstruction first.

Comment: Does the case matter for all the %escaped characters?

Comment: This matters for something like OAuth where the difference between `%2f` and `%2F` is enough to make your signature invalid - http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#encoding_parameters

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will *uppercase* all escaped characters in your string.

```
string url = "http://whatever.com/something";
string lower = Server.UrlEncode(url);
Regex reg = new Regex(@"%[a-f0-9]{2}");
string upper = reg.Replace(lower, m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
```

Comment: that's its agent-j, but without extra ")", Thanks!

Comment: thanks for this. For some reason Twitter's OAuth requires the escaped characters to be in uppercase or else it'll give you 401 unauthorized

Comment: Thanks! (BTW, the reason this is necessary for OAuth is that the entire URL ("http://" and all) is URLEncoded and then signed. The OAuth 1.0 spec requires uppercase hexadicemal for encoded characters, but the .net UrlEncode produces lowercase - the difference causes the signatures to not match.)

Comment: @SAGExSDX: I have uppercase the url that needed to create the oauth_signature. But it still give me the 401 error. If you have the C# code, can you share it me please ?

Comment: @user1457039 var lower = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strText);

            var reg = new Regex(@"%[a-f0-9]{2}");

            return reg.Replace(lower, m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());

It's the same as the above answer.

Answer (score 24):

```
Uri.EscapeDataString("http://")
```

This code return

```
http%3A%2F%2F
```

Comment: my favorite. Why use regex when you can use this?

Comment: This the correct answer:
If you had used 
HttpUtility.UrlEncode('http://');
to encode it would incorrectly return lowercase encode letters, which I was incorrectly using for signatures in Oauth http requests.

Comment: This doesn't escape square brackets: []

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem, I found the answer in this link:

[WebUtility.UrlEncode or HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://edi.wang/post/2018/11/25/netcore-webutility-urlencode-httputility-urlencode)

in-short you can use:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode
```

which encodes into uppercase hex values

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy

```
Regex.Replace( encodedString, @"%[a-f\d]{2}", m => m.Value.ToUpper() )
```

I.e. replace all hex letter-digit combinations to upper case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "http" is always the first four characters then you simply split the string after "http", `UrlEncode` that part and then call `ToUpper()` on it. Then join back together with "http" as your prefix.